# How do I simplify agents/processes in discrete events simulation (Anylogic)?

Tags: process, anylogic

I have a full DES model of a clinic. The patient is the main actor. 
When a patient goes in a room, it will see different staff. I had to duplicate the patient in order for it to ‘call’ another staff type (e.g. B) while it is busy with staff A.  Furthermore, a staff can come in and out of the exam room multiple times; thus, there is a lot of parallelism in the exam room regarding the staff (in-out, many different staff).

I created a Room agent using the “port-in/port-out”. If I keep just ‘one room’, patient X may combine with patient Z (having duplicated multiple times the patients, as well as service times are different).

Thus, I created 18 individual rooms. The model got extremely big and I am having problems running it (or even saving it) (and I am running it at the maximum capacity of the computer – 4 cores and 10G of RAM).

My question is: 
What other way can I have 18 rooms without creating each one of them independently?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi Alex, welcome to SOF. This is too broad a question and lacks details to understand what you did. Can you please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and return here to make your question specific, reproducible and understandable? (It is not clear why your model is so slow: 18 room agents with processes inside them does not sound very tough...)

Comment: I have re-edited to situation while providing more details. Thx for your input.

Comment: much better, thx. How do you create the 18 rooms? Ist it 1 agent type living in an agent population of 18? Or 18 different agent types? There seems something fundamentally broken. Even from what you describe, it seems very difficult to reach 10 GB of RAM usage. I suspect you might have a memory leak somewhere: something is not deleted that could be deleted (old agents?) or something logs ridiculous data (patient position every milisecond?)...

Comment: Clarifications:
I created 18 different room agents – this is the reason why the model got so big (and attempting to find other ways to have the 18 rooms.
I tried creating a population of 18 room agents – this makes the model a lot more manageable. However, when I run the model I get an error: “Exception during discrete event execution: root.PatientGoingToRoom1: Out Port root.PatientGoingToRoom1.out can't be connected with more than one In Port. Currently it has at least two connections: root.ProcessInExamRoom1[0].in and root.ProcessInExamRoom1[1].in.”

Comment: The Java heap size memory fluctuates between 5G and 8G when having 18 different/independent room agents when I am working on it (I am not referring when I Run the model).
The old agents are getting deleted. The model time unites are minutes.

Comment: Sorry to say but there is something deeply flawed in your model. 18 different rooms with process charts and a few hundred patients do not eat 8GB of memory :-) That error message also indicates structural issues... Strip your model bit by bit back to its bare bones to see when memory is back to nromal (500-2000MB max for your setup) and find the root cause. Impossible to fix otherwise

Comment: Each room (individually) has ~2800 elements (including the connectors). Almost within each process block, I have references and calculations (parameters and variables).
Regarding the error message, I used the model Emergency Department in the AnyLogic library; I built my logic in the exact same manner. (this is why it was strange for me to see that error message).

Every time that I was adding a new part to the model I was checking it (smaller model just to make sure that all the elements behave in the manner that I intended). I had no issues with this.

Comment: Still, my main question is what other manner is there to do double/copy/duplicate processes where my copied agents can come back/reconnect to their own selves? 
Regards, Alex

Comment: Extra info: Emergency Department Model Anylogic - uSoundProcess and xRayProcess --- here is the 'agent process' that i mimicked